# MYSQL Subtract a record from multiple row with FCFS

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a inventory table of item_in and item_out. Now whatever item goes out from inventory should be on basis of FCFS.

Now what i want how much items are remaining in the stock.
My inwards table has these columns:
inward_id, in_item_id, in_price, in_qty.
My outward table is
outward_id, out_item_id, out_price, out_qty.

Items should go out on FCFS basis.
This is my item_out table

```
 id     item    price,     qty
 1     '11'  '35.9200'  '616.1700'
 2     '11'  '35.9200'  '9.7500'
 3     '11'  '36.0000'  '11.4400'
 4     '11'  '36.0000'  '73.9200'
 5     '11'  '36.0000'  '52.8000'
 6     '11'  '36.0000'  '40.9200'
 7     '11'  '36.0000'  '22.2300'
 8     '11'  '36.0000'  '14.3200'
```

This is my item_in table.

```
id  item    price   quantity
1   '11' '35.9200' '625.9200'
2   '11' '36.0000' '640.0000'
3   '11' '36.0000' '320.3000'
4   '11' '36.0000' '160.0000'
5   '11' '36.0000' '520.1500'
6   '11' '36.0000' '640.0000'
```

Now what i want is from item_in table

```
id  item    price   quantity   remaining
1   '11' '35.9200' '625.9200'  0
2   '11' '36.0000' '640.0000'  424.3700
3   '11' '36.0000' '320.3000'  320.3000
4   '11' '36.0000' '160.0000'  160.0000
5   '11' '36.0000' '520.1500'  520.1500
6   '11' '36.0000' '640.0000'  640.0000
```

Please help here. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you had chosen nice, small, round numbers, I might have stood a chance.

Comment: i am noob in programing bro. I need help. Suggest please.

Comment: My suggestion is above.

Comment: that are numbers bro not strings or varchar.